# How to determine the resistor value when I want to use this op amp circuit?

Tags: operational-amplifier, bridge-rectifier

I want to know how to determine the resistor value when I am using this op-amp circuit.

Any theory I need to follow? How to determine the gain with diodes? If possible, please explain with an example.

This circuit is from [here.](https://itp.nyu.edu/archive/physcomp-spring2014/sensors/Schematics/LM358OpAmp.html)

[image]

Comment: Anson, you do realize that op-amps require power supplies?

Comment: oh...I forgot about this problem...sorry for my negligence. But maybe this question is a good opportunity for me to learn more about op-amp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first vertically connected 100k ohm resistor (let R1) is used to make the current value flowing into ground very less. High resistance is used so that the overall power consumption of the circuit is low as power depends more on I^2 factor than R^1 factor.

Now you have used R1, you may ask why is there only one negative feedback resistor (let R2) why not 2. This is because, you want your op-amps to have as low as possible **input bias current** i.e. the current flowing in the +ve and -ve terminals of op-amp.

**To limit this current, the thevenin resistance as seen from +ve and -ve terminals should be same.**

For +ve terminal the thevenin resistance is 100kohm i.e. R1, hence for -ve terminal same value resistor R2 is connected as a negative feedback i.e. 100kohm .

This is not connected b/w -ve terminal and ground because that will add up to the power consumption because the resistance will be at rectifiers output then.

For next dc gain stage, this is a simple **negative feedback op-amp with very high gain**. This is to convert the mili Volts to Volts so that the micro-controller ahead can read the the signals properly, as, if mili volts is directly fed to the micro controller it may always read it low.

Answer (score 0):

the piezo has high impedenace it's essentially a current source

ther diodes are a rectifier converting the AC from the piezo to DC

the 100K resistors set the sensitivity of the first op-amp.

the 3M and 10K set the gain of the second amplifier.

Answer (score 0):

Very high resistor values will be vulnerable to capacitances on Vin+ and Vin-; I always assume 10pf on any node; the RC product tells you the time-delay and thus the phaseshift; lots of phaseshift risks oscillation.

Also, high R values have higher builtin random noise voltages. A 100,000 ohm resistor in 1MHz bandwidth has 40 microVolts RMS noise (about 250 microVolts peakpeak at the 1ppm occurrence). A 1Megohm would be sqrt(10) noisier. A 10Megohm would be sqrt(100) noisier

However, as Jasen pointed out, your sensor produces a current while the applied torque or pressure is changing, and a 100,000 ohm resistor is a sensitive current-voltage converter.

Lower value resistors:

1) require more power

2) are less random-electron-movement noisy

3) produce less phaseshift, so can be trusted for precision at high frequencies

4) require more current be dumped into the GND as needed in the second stage; you
easily have 5 milliohms GND resistance which has a horrid temperature coefficient ( 0.4%per degree C).

**by the way** to protect the opamp, I'd place 2 diodes in parallel as clamp diodes from Vin- to Vin+.